# Are there any special permissions to use the YouTube API to list sponsors?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm using the YouTube API to retrieve a channel's sponsor list. It was working correctly a few days ago, but on 2019-12-13 started returning error 403:

> Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized.

I can make the user log in and give permissions to the app. The error happens when I try to retrieve the sponsor list from the user's channel.

Excerpt from the code I am using:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly');
$client->setClientId('CLIENT_ID');
$client->setClientSecret('CLIENT_SECRET');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setAccessToken([
    'access_token' => 'TOKEN',
    'refresh_token' => 'REFRESH_TOKEN',
    'expires_in' => 'EXPIRES_IN',
]);

$params = [
    'filter' => 'all',
    'maxResults' => 50
];

$service = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
$response = $service->sponsors->listSponsors('snippet', $params);
```

**How to fix this error? What do I need to change?**

Additional Information:

- I followed the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/sponsors/list) and, as I said, it was working;
- The OAuth consent screen has the status "Published";
- The YouTube Data API v3 are enabled;
- I am using the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly`;
- I am using a OAuth 2.0 credential;
- I can access other services within the class "Google_Service_YouTube" less related to the sponsors;
- For the purpose of testing, I created 2 other projects and generated the clients and the same error 403 was returned.

Thanks!

[EDIT]

I still couldn't solve the problem...

I did some tests with "OAuth 2.0 Playground" and when I use the default settings I get the sponsor list, but when I put the client ID of my project it gives error 403.

I have no idea why the request starts to return the error. There were no changes to the code or project settings.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same issue. Did you find a solve?

Comment: @BarryCarlyon Not yet... A month ago I posted about it on [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147349589) and two people said they have the same problem as me. Unfortunately, that's all I got. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sponsors.list` has been replaced by `members.list`.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/members/list